# Recursion to print out any iteration of the given numbers so that the sum is equal to a given number

Tags: c, recursion

We are given an array of numbers `[2,6]` and the the sum should be 10 and we are required to print out any iteration so that the sum of that array is equal to 10 in this case those being

```
2,2,2,2,2
6,2,2
2,6,2
2,2,6
```

this is my code for now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct val_s {
    int num_choice;
    int *choices;
} val_t;

int sum(int *sol,int pos,int n) {
    int s=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        s=s+sol[i];
    }
    if(s==n)
        return 1;

    return 0;

}

void mult_princ(val_t *val,int *sol, int n, int pos)
{

    if(sum(sol,pos,n))
    {
        for (int i = 0;  i< pos; i++) {
            printf("%d ",sol[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < val[i].num_choice; ++i) {
        sol[pos]=val[pos].choices[i];
        mult_princ(val,sol,n,pos+1);
    }
    return;
}
int main() {

    int *sol;
    val_t *val;
    int n=10;
    val = malloc(n*sizeof(val_t));
    if (val == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        val[i].num_choice=2;
        val[i].choices = malloc(val[i].num_choice * sizeof(int));
        if (val[i].choices == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        val[i].choices[0] = 2;
        val[i].choices[1] = 6;

    }
    sol = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (sol == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    mult_princ(val,sol,n,0);

    return 0;
}
```

My idea on how to solve this was:

We build a recursive function that adds the numbers 1 by 1 and when the given condition is mentioned it prints out the array. Every time we recur we check the exit condition in which there is another function called sum which takes the current array and the current size (pos in this case) and does the sum. If the sum is what i want it will return 1 which will allow the recursion to exit.

At least this is what i tried to go for but all it prints is a `2,2,2,2,2` and a very big negative number for exit number meaning that there is a problem somewhere.

Comment: Compiled using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Gave no warnings. Great! Either you're using warnings or you got "lucky". /// Running it results in a protection violation (SIGSEGV). Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` is great at debugging those. Gives [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EczTW94aY). It tells us that `i` is going beyond the size of `val` in `for (int i = 0; i < val[i].num_choice; ++i)`.

Comment: Why do you have an array of identical `val_t`? You should only have one. `.choices` is the array of choices.

Comment: @ikegami Im trying to implement this using the multiplication method from combinatorics and thats how its implemented. We take one structure with 2 elements and imagine forming a tree where one branch is first number and other branch is 2nd numbers. And for every child you split further. At least thats how its explained in the slides i have here. And at the end you recur and print out every solution. Thats why i have many iterations of the same structure

Comment: Does the order matter? Are 2,2,6; 2,6,2; and 6,2,2 the same result, or three results? You have them listed as three, but these are sums which suggest an equivalence. It's a lot easier if they are equivalent.

Comment: @ikegami nope. Order doesnt matter. We should print all of them 2,2,6; 2,6,2; and 6,2,2

Comment: ok, but that means order *does* matter.

Comment: @ikegami ... right im sorry but i think you get the gist.

Comment: You have an array of identical `val_t` structures, and that makes no sense. I think the fundamental problem is that you are confusing the choice *available* (2, 6), and the choices *made* (e.g. 2, 2, 2, 2, 2).

Comment: @ikegami so what do you suppose then

Comment: `n`, unfortunately is being used 2 ways.  `n` is the target _sum_, yet `n` is also the number of `val_t`.  @Severjan Lici, Why the same?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i noticed that as well but i didnt change it cuz i thought it didnt really matter. Im not trying for any efficiency at the moment or making it look pretty im just looking to make it work.

Comment: Running in a debugger shows the segfault is caused here `sol[pos]=val[pos].choices[i];` when `pos` is `10`. Which is outside your array(s).

Comment: Re "*Running in a debugger shows the segfault is caused here*",  woops, I misread the line numbers in my initial comment. Indeed, the line you gave is what `-fsanitize=address` showed.

Comment: I suspect the `+1` in `mult_princ(val,sol,n,pos+1);` might be going out of bounds.

Comment: Aside: use meaningful variable names. What is a `sol` or a `pos` or `n`? Someone else might have to try to read this code in a year's time. It might be you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of identical `val_t` structures, and that makes no sense.

I think the fundamental problem is that you are confusing the *options available* (2, 6), and the *choices made* (e.g. 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) to arrive at the sum.

There is a simple solution that uses recursion.

First, you will want a vector of available options. It doesn't change during the algorithm.

You will also need a second vector which contains the choices you have made up until now. It will need up to *floor( target / smallest_option )* elements. It is initially empty.

The recursive solution would look like this:

1. solve( options, choices, target ):

   1. If target is zero,

      1. Print out the vector of choices.
      2. Return.
   2. For each option,

      1. If the option is less than or equal to the target,

         1. Append option to the list of choices.
         2. Call ourselves, but pass the target minus the option as the target.
         3. Remove the previously appended option from the list of choices.

That's it. And since you already know the maximum number of choices, allocating memory for the choices can be done up front, so adding and removing elements from the choices is extremely trivial.

The exact implementation of vectors is up you. You could use a struct like you are currently doing, or the size and the array of values could be separate parameters.

Comment: Does this mean that i have to reallocate the size of the array that contains the elements each time? because we increasing the size is some cases like in 2,2,2,2,2? And if so do we do it inside the recursive function?

Comment: No. I specifically addressed this in the question. Twice. "It will need up to *floor( target / smallest_option )* elements." and "since you already know the maximum number of choices, it can be done up front". Though that's supposed to read "allocating memory can be done up front"  floor( 10 / 2 ) = 5, the maximum number of elements you'll need for the example inputs.

Comment: i think im starting to form the idea ill just need like some times to put it into code. Thanks for the advice

Comment: If you come back in a week and ask as a comment here, I'll show you my implementation.

Comment: xdd hopefully it wont come to that

Comment: I meant, if you want to compare with what you come up with. I've already written it.

Comment: then ill keep it in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The key problem code has is when `sum(sol,pos,n)` does not return *true* (sum found), it continues, even if the sum exceeds `n`.  This leads to  infinite recusion.

A quick fix simply prevents excessive recursion.

```
void mult_princ(val_t *val, int *sol, int n, size_t pos) {
  if (pos >= n) {
    return;
  }
  ...
```

Output

```
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 6 
2 6 2 
6 2 2
```

A better solution would have `sum(sol,pos,n)` return -1,0,1 to indicate sum too small, sum just right, sum too large.

```
// if(sum(sol,pos,n))
int result = sum(sol,pos,n);
if (result > 0) return;
if (result == 0) {
  // print solution, then return
}
// Continue on and recurse.
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but ill think abut this tomorrow since over here its already 5 am and my brain is on potato level maintenance